# Using std::any_cast with decltype ... why does this code throw a bad any_cast?

Tags: c++, c++17

I am using std::any_cast in combination with decltype:

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>

auto bar(char c) { return (c == 'i' ? 42 : true);}

auto foo(char c) { return (c == 'i' ? 42 : (c == 'd' ? 4.4 : true));}

int main() {
  std::any MyInt = 123456789;
  std::cout << std::any_cast<decltype(bar('i'))>(MyInt)
            << std::endl;  // works just fine
  std::cout << std::any_cast<decltype(foo('i'))>(MyInt)
            << std::endl;  // throws bad any_cast
}
```

You can [see online at Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4k2E2e) that the cast using `bar` works fine while the version using `foo` throws a bad any_cast. Why is this the case and how can I fix the `foo` version?

**I am well aware of the fact, that I could just use `std::any_cast<int>(MyInt)`. But I really want to use decltype and the `foo` version of the function. Thanks!**

Answer (score 2):

Both operands of a ternary expression must be of the same type. In an expression like

```
c == 'i' ? 42 : true;
```

the return type is `int`, since `true` can be converted to an `int`. Hence `bar` returns a `int` .

By the same logic, `foo` returns a `double`. So when you do the `any_cast` of an `int` to a `double`, it fails.

You can check this with

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(bar('i')),int>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(foo('i')),double>);
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please tell me how to modify `foo` so that `decltype(foo('i'))` returns an int and `decltype(foo('d'))` returns a double and `decltype(foo('b'))` returns a bool?

Comment: @BlueTune You cannot. The return type of a function cannot depend on the runtime argument.

Answer (score 2):

The return type of a function is independent from any instance passed to the function itself. You can do data dependent type lookups only at compile time with something like this:

```
template <char C>
struct foo {
  using type = bool;
};
template <>
struct foo<'i'> {
  using type = int;
};
template <>
struct foo<'d'> {
  using type = double;
};

template <char C>
using foo_t = typename foo<C>::type;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<foo_t<'d'>,double>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<foo_t<'i'>,int>);

std::any_cast<foo_t<'i'>>(MyInt); // fine
```